# Dispatch is not a function, will remove ticket from database but throws error saying dispatch is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, redux

Everything works and it will delete the ticket when you click the delete button but at // Delete ticket in ticket actions it says that dispatch is not a function. I'm trying to be able to delete the specific ticket that is clicked and will also add an edit ticket button.

Tickets.js higher level

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import TicketItem from './TicketItem';
import { getCurrentUsersTickets, deleteTickets } from '../../actions/tickets';

const Tickets = ({ getCurrentUsersTickets, tickets: { tickets, loading } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentUsersTickets();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <h1 className='large text-primary'>Your Active Tickets</h1>
          <div className='container'>
            {tickets.length > 0 ? (
              tickets.map(tickets => (
                <TicketItem
                  key={tickets._id}
                  tickets={tickets}
                  deleteTickets={deleteTickets}
                />
              ))
            ) : (
              <h4>No tickets found...</h4>
            )}
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Tickets.propTypes = {
  getCurrentUsersTickets: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  tickets: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteTickets: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tickets: state.tickets
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getCurrentUsersTickets,
  deleteTickets
})(Tickets);
```

Ticketitems.js child component

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const TicketItem = ({
  tickets: {
    _id,
    title,
    fromBuilding,
    fromRoom,
    toBuilding,
    toRoom,
    contactNumber,
    description,
    reasonForMove
  },
  deleteTickets
}) => {
  return (
    <div className='accordion' id={`userTickets${_id}`}>
      <div className='card'>
        <div className='card-header' id={`userTicketsHeading${_id}`}>
          <h2 className='mb-0'>
            <button
              className='btn btn-link'
              type='button'
              data-toggle='collapse'
              data-target={`#collapse${_id}`}
              aria-expanded='true'
              aria-controls={`collapse${_id}`}
            >
              {title}
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>

        <div
          id={`collapse${_id}`}
          className='collapse'
          aria-labelledby={`userTicketsHeading${_id}`}
          data-parent={`#userTickets${_id}`}
        >
          <div className='card-body'>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>From Building:</span>{' '}
                {fromBuilding}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>From Room:</span>{' '}
                {fromRoom}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>To Building:</span>{' '}
                {toBuilding}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>To Building:</span>{' '}
                {toRoom}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>Contact Number:</span>{' '}
                {contactNumber}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>Description:</span>{' '}
                {description}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>Reason For Move:</span>{' '}
                {reasonForMove}
              </li>
            </ul>
            <button className='btn btn-danger' onClick={deleteTickets(_id)}>
              Delete Ticket
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

TicketItem.propTypes = {
  tickets: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteTickets: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default TicketItem;
```

ticket actions

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { setAlert } from './alert';

import { GET_USERS_TICKETS, TICKETS_ERROR, DELETE_TICKETS } from './types';

// Get tickets
export const getCurrentUsersTickets = () => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('/api/tickets/me');

    dispatch({
      type: GET_USERS_TICKETS,
      payload: res.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: TICKETS_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};

// Create
export const createTickets = (formData, history) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    };

    const res = await axios.post('/api/tickets', formData, config);

    dispatch({
      type: GET_USERS_TICKETS,
      payload: res.data
    });

    history.push('/dashboard');
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = err.response.data.errors;

    if (errors) {
      errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
    }

    dispatch({
      type: TICKETS_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};

// Delete ticket
export const deleteTickets = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    await axios.delete(`/api/tickets/delete/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_TICKETS,
      payload: id
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('err response', err);
    // dispatch({
    //   type: TICKETS_ERROR,
    //   payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    // });
  }
};
```

ticket reducers

```
import {
  GET_USERS_TICKETS,
  TICKETS_ERROR,
  CLEAR_TICKETS,
  DELETE_TICKETS
} from '../actions/types';

const initialState = {
  tickets: [],
  loading: true,
  error: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case GET_USERS_TICKETS:
      return {
        ...state,
        tickets: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case TICKETS_ERROR:
      return {
        ...state,
        error: payload,
        loading: false
      };
    case CLEAR_TICKETS:
      return {
        ...state,
        tickets: [],
        loading: false
      };
    case DELETE_TICKETS:
      return {
        ...state,
        tickets: state.tickets.filter(
          tickets => tickets._id !== action.payload
        ),
        loading: false
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, since you are using async calls in the Redux actions you would need to use Redux middleware to handle the promises, such as, [Redux-Promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-promise) or [Redux-Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk).

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to place deleteTickets action as a prop on the Ticket component so it could be passed into the  in the return section to go to the child component. Then on TicketItem.js had the wrong format for the Delete Button needed onClick={() => deleteTickets(_id)}. Late night and tunnel vison on possible fix missed the simple fix

Tickets.js

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Spinner from '../layout/Spinner';
import TicketItem from './TicketItem';
import { getCurrentUsersTickets, deleteTickets } from '../../actions/tickets';

const Tickets = ({
  getCurrentUsersTickets,
  tickets: { tickets, loading },
  // added deleteTickets  
  deleteTickets
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getCurrentUsersTickets();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <Fragment>
          <h1 className='large text-primary'>Your Active Tickets</h1>
          <div className='container'>
            {tickets.length > 0 ? (
              tickets.map(tickets => (
                <TicketItem
                  key={tickets._id}
                  tickets={tickets}
                  deleteTickets={deleteTickets}
                />
              ))
            ) : (
              <h4>No tickets found...</h4>
            )}
          </div>
        </Fragment>
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Tickets.propTypes = {
  getCurrentUsersTickets: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  tickets: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteTickets: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  tickets: state.tickets
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getCurrentUsersTickets,
  deleteTickets
})(Tickets);
```

TicketItem.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const TicketItem = ({
  tickets: {
    _id,
    title,
    fromBuilding,
    fromRoom,
    toBuilding,
    toRoom,
    contactNumber,
    description,
    reasonForMove
  },
  deleteTickets
}) => {
  return (
    <div className='accordion' id={`userTickets${_id}`}>
      <div className='card'>
        <div className='card-header' id={`userTicketsHeading${_id}`}>
          <h2 className='mb-0'>
            <button
              className='btn btn-link'
              type='button'
              data-toggle='collapse'
              data-target={`#collapse${_id}`}
              aria-expanded='true'
              aria-controls={`collapse${_id}`}
            >
              {title}
            </button>
          </h2>
        </div>

        <div
          id={`collapse${_id}`}
          className='collapse'
          aria-labelledby={`userTicketsHeading${_id}`}
          data-parent={`#userTickets${_id}`}
        >
          <div className='card-body'>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>From Building:</span>{' '}
                {fromBuilding}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>From Room:</span>{' '}
                {fromRoom}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>To Building:</span>{' '}
                {toBuilding}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>To Building:</span>{' '}
                {toRoom}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>Contact Number:</span>{' '}
                {contactNumber}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>Description:</span>{' '}
                {description}
              </li>
              <li>
                <span className='font-weight-bolder'>Reason For Move:</span>{' '}
                {reasonForMove}
              </li>
            </ul>
            <button
              className='btn btn-danger'
              // Reformated onClick
              onClick={() => deleteTickets(_id)}
            >
              Delete Ticket
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

TicketItem.propTypes = {
  tickets: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteTickets: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default TicketItem;
```